# WP_Query filtering in ACF field containing dates

Tags: wp-query, filters, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, date

I'm trying to use WP_Query to filter Advanced Custom Fields posts that can contain this value in the "dates" field (text type), for example "20230101-20230102;20230201-20230202;20230301-20230302" using 2 inputs (date type): from; to.

This means that if the user specifies that he/she is looking for posts between 31/12/2022 and 05/01/2023, the post containing the above example in the "dates" field will be displayed.

Conversely, he should not see a post whose "dates" field contains the value "20221229-20231230;20230201-20230202;20230301-20230302".

I've created this code, but it only works if the "from", "to", or full date matches exactly. In addition, so far it only works so that there can only be one date in the "dates" field in the format "20230101-20230102":

```
$args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'dates',
                'value' => $from->format('Ymd') . '-' . $to->format('Ymd'),
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'dates',
                'value' => $from->format('Ymd') . '-',
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'dates',
                'value' => '-' . $to->format('Ymd'),
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
        );
```